# get 8 digit unique value when sequence of 7 positive integers given as input

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a random sequence of numbers, like 1, 4, 15, 21, 27, 15... There are no constraints on what numbers may appear in the sequence and the sequence consist of 7 positive integers and each integer range from 0 to 255.The question is, do we have a function that will give unique output by performing mathematical operations on this sequence? By unique, I mean when the function is applied on sequence A, it must output a value that's different from the output obtained by applying the same function on any other sequence (or the same sequence but numbers placed in different order) in the world.and i need the output in 8 digits only.thanks

Comment: Very confusing. You write, "There are no constraints on what numbers may appear in the sequence," but then you proceed to give two constraints on what numbers may appear in the sequence, namely, "the sequence consist[s] of 7 positive integers" and "each integer range from 0 to 255." Moreover, the second constraint seems to allow zero, while the first constraint forbids it, as zero isn't positive. No matter; under any reasonable interpretation of what you want, Robert has shown you can't have it.

Comment: Actually sir i have an application that work like it take 7 inputs from user in range of 0-255 and generate an 8 digit number. and sorry im correcting my question the sequence produce single output regardless of order of elements i-e {1,2,3,....} should generate same result as {3,2,1..} or {1,3,2...}

Comment: Even so, the number of 7-element subsets of $\{\,1,2,\dots,255\,\}$ is the binomial coefficient 255-choose-7. If that's bigger than the number of 8-digit numbers (which is either $10^8$ or $9\times10^7$, depending on interpretation), then no can do.

Comment: So are you OK with what's been posted as comments and answer now?

Comment: Earth to Tehseen, come in, please.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**  ${}{}{}{}$

$$256^7 > 10^8$$

Comment: kindly explain it

Comment: There are more possible inputs than possible outputs.

Comment: so we can't get the output in 8 digits?

Comment: i have tried the continued fraction but that give ma a very big number.

Comment: Look up the pigeonhole principle.